# Makefile: building LaTeX files in subdirectories with two versions of each file

Tags: makefile, latex

I have the following folder structure

```
   1st-grade-math-class/
      common/
        mystyle.sty
        mysubstyle.sty
        fonts/
          font1.ttf
          font2.ttf
          font3.ttf
      week01/
        handout.tex
        image1.pdf
        image2.pdf
      week02/
        handout.tex
        image1.pdf
        image2.pdf
      ...
      week13/
        handout.tex
      output/
        [empty]
```

And I would like to create a Makefile - in the best way - to do the following:

- make sure I include the *common* directory properly in TEXINPUTS
- compile the *handout.tex* into a PDF (using either pdflatex or xelatex) and have it in the *output* directory as *week01-handout-student.pdf*
- compile the *handout.tex* with a line of LaTeX prepended to the beginning of the file (that sets a flag) into a PDF and have it in the *output* directory as *week01-handout-teacher.pdf*
- clean everything up (the log, aux, etc. files)

I am not sure I know how to this in any other way than manually duplicating an elementary Makefile/bash script in every subdirectory, then calling each of them one by one with a for loop.

I would appreciate help on how to build this process, ideally with a single Makefile in the root directory. Thanks.

**UPDATE:** I purposefully did not want to give any details about how I compile LaTeX, in case somebody has a better suggestion than my current usage. Right now I am using Latexmk (which is already a make-like wrapper of LaTeX):

- *latexmk -pdf file.tex* generates *file.pdf*
- to add the line of code, I do a simple echo "line of code" > temp.tex and cat handout.tex >> temp.tex, then the same latexmk command
- *latexmk -c file.tex* in a directory cleans all temporary files used to compile file.tex
- TEXINPUTS is the TeX path variable, to let TeX find (in its path) the style files: I do TEXINPUTS=full-path-to/common and then export TEXINPUTS before compiling anything.

If anybody has a better suggestion, I am a willing taker.

Comment: Can you provide the basic commands necessary to generate the LaTeX output you want? Is `TEXINPUTS` just a variable that needs to point to the `common` directory before running whatever latex processing command is run? Also samples of the log, aux, etc. filenames and locations? Does the cleaning need to happen automatically at generation time or is a separate `clean` target sufficient?

Comment: @EtanReisner Thanks for your interest; I added some detail in my post. TEXINPUTS is TeX's path variable, and just needs to point to the full path of common. The log, aux, etc. files are file.log, file.aux (for "file.tex"). The tool I use already provides a convenient way to clean everything. A sufficient clean target is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do what you want I believe:

```
OUTDIR := output

# Tell make to export this environment variable to all recipe lines it runs.
export TEXINPUTS := $(abspath common)

# Get the list of all of our week directories.
weekdirs := $(wildcard week*)
#$(info weekdirs:$(weekdirs))

# Create student output filenames from week directory names.
STUDENT_HANDOUTS := $(patsubst %,$(OUTDIR)/%-handout-student.pdf,$(weekdirs))
#$(info STUDENT_HANDOUTS:$(STUDENT_HANDOUTS))

# Create teacher output filenames from week directory names.
TEACHER_HANDOUTS := $(patsubst %,$(OUTDIR)/%-handout-teacher.pdf,$(weekdirs))
#$(info TEACHER_HANDOUTS:$(TEACHER_HANDOUTS))

# Default target depends on all output files.
all: $(STUDENT_HANDOUTS) $(TEACHER_HANDOUTS)

# Pattern rule for building pdf files.
%.pdf:
        @echo + Making $@ from $^
        @echo cd $(@D) && echo latexmx -pdf $(abspath $<)
        @echo cd $(@D) && echo latexmk -c $(abspath $<)

# Static pattern rule mapping student output files to input files.
$(STUDENT_HANDOUTS) : $(OUTDIR)/%-handout-student.pdf : %/handout.tex

# Pattern rule to generate temporary input files from original input files.
%/handout-tmp.tex: %/handout.tex
        @echo echo 'line of code' '>' $@
        @echo cat $^ '>>' $@

# Static pattern rule mapping teacher output files to (temporary) input files.
$(TEACHER_HANDOUTS) : $(OUTDIR)/%-handout-teacher.pdf : %/handout-tmp.tex
```

Uncomment the `$(info)` lines to see a bit of how the variables are put together.

This uses `latexmk -c` to clean up auxiliary files after creating the output files.

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately this doesn't work. For some reason when I do all these commands (after typing TEXINPUTS=..path-to-common, and export TEXINPUTS) in a bash shell, it all works perfectly. When run with the makefile, LaTeX complains that it cannot find the main class, which is "exam.cls" -- this indicates that the TeX search path are messed up. When I comment the TEXINPUTS line in the Makefile, it seems like LaTeX no longer has trouble finding exam.cls, a standard class, but of course can't find my styles in the common folder. I hate Make; these are the issues you ALWAYS have.

Comment: What value *exactly* are you setting for `TEXINPUTS` when you run this from your shell? Using that *exact* value in the makefile fails? Can you get `latexmk`/etc. to spit the paths it is using out at you? Does adding `SHELL=/bin/bash` to the makefile change anything?

Comment: my mistake this doesn't seem to be a Makefile issue. I wrote the same thing as a Python script, and I have the exact same issue. When I am running the program myself, TEXINPUTS is initially empty, and set to the absolute path of common, then exported. I assume when we do this in the Makefile (or Python) it erases part of the environment. The shell does not change anything.

Comment: What sets the variable shouldn't matter (and I can't really see how it even could). Are you sure you are using the *exact* same value? Quick searching online seems to indicate that you want a trailing `:` on the value of `TEXINPUTS` to keep the default path while prefixing your own.

Comment: You're absolutely right about this issue. However there is still something wrong, and I cannot figure what it is :/ (I am investigating).

Answer (score 1):

*Technique 1*. The `echo foo >$@; cat $< >>$@` thing is something I've done before; I think it's reasonable.

*Technique 2*. Another technique is to have your `.tex` document, or a package file it uses, include a line like:

```
\InputIfFileExists{lecturenotes.config}{}{}
```

That allows you to make certain adjustments in a makefile, as in for example:

```
# any bits of configuration that should be in all the .config files
SWITCHES=\makeindex

%-notes.pdf: %.tex
        printf '$(SWITCHES)\\ExecuteOptions{sidenotes}\n' >lecturenotes.config
        TEXINPUTS=styles: pdflatex $<
        mv ${<:.tex=.pdf} $@    
        rm lecturenotes.config

%-single.pdf: %.tex
        printf '$(SWITCHES)\\ExecuteOptions{oneside}\n' >lecturenotes.config
        TEXINPUTS=styles: pdflatex $<
        mv ${<:.tex=.pdf} $@
        rm lecturenotes.config
```

*Technique 3*. A third technique for controlling LaTeX from outside is to include in your document (or in a package file):

```
\newif\ifdemonstrator
\expandafter\ifx\csname demonstrator\endcsname\relax
  \demonstratorfalse
\else
  \demonstratortrue
\fi
...
\ifdemonstrator
    \typeout{Demonstrator is TRUE}
\else
    \typeout{Demonstrator is FALSE}
\fi
```

Then call latex with:

```
%-plain.pdf: %.tex
    latex $<
    mv ${<:.tex=.pdf} $@

%-demo.pdf: %.tex
    latex --jobname ${<:.tex=} '\def\demonstrator{x}\input{$<}`
    mv ${<:.tex=.pdf} $@
```

---

Technique 1 is a bit of a blunt instrument, but if that's all that's needed, it's pretty lightweight.

Technique 2 is probably the most neatly engineered, but it is slightly more effort.

Technique 3 is probably the one I use most in this sort of circumstance.